Components re-rendering making the app crash - Expo
I'm learning react-native/expo.
When I type anything, the whole page re-renders. I know that because in the code I upload an image and in console I see the image uri. So when I type, I see it again and again until the app crashes.
JS Fiddle code
I uploaded here the whole code because it's too long.
The flow is - Fill the form - upload image if needed - press the confirm button
I tried using useCallback, but with no success.
MRE as requested:
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image  } from 'react-native';
import KeyboardWrapper from '../KeyboardWrapper';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

const FormComponent = ({ onSave }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    driverName1: '',
      });
const [images, setImages] = useState([]); // State to store captured images

// Function to handle image capture
  const handleCaptureImage = useCallback(async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      alert('Camera permission is required to take pictures.');
      return;
    }
  
    try {
      const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: false,
        aspect: [16, 9],
        quality: 1,
      });

      if (!result.cancelled && result.assets.length > 0) {
        // Add the new image URI to the images state
        setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, result.assets[0].uri]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error capturing image:', error);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleChange = useCallback((name, value) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  }, [formData]);
 return (
    <KeyboardWrapper>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.form}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Sofer 1"
        value={formData.driverName1}
        onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('driverName1', text)}
        style={styles.textInput}
      />
     {/* Display captured images */}
      <View style={styles.formImgs}>
        {images.map((imageUri, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={styles.img}>
              {console.log('Image URI:', imageUri)}
            <Image
              source={{ uri: imageUri }}
              style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
            />
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.formAction}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleCaptureImage}>
            <View style={styles.btn}>
              <Text style={styles.btnText}>Scaneaza</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    </KeyboardWrapper>
  );
};


Short video of the problem using MRE

Can you make a MRE?

@asyncawait just added a MRE.

Video link says: "This video isn’t ready
Ask the video creator to sign up and share this with you again to preview."

@asyncawait uploaded on youtube. It should work now.

I believe the component re-rendering is a default feature of React. If you want more granular control over when your component re-renders, you're probably looking for React.memo. Wrapping a component in this will prevent it from rerendering by default.


const { useState, memo } = React;

const ImgDisplay = memo(({ imgs }) => {
  console.log("rendering ImgDisplay");
  return (
    <div>
      {
        imgs.map((img, i) => <div key={i}>{img}</div>)
      }
    </div>
  )
})

const Example = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");

  const captureImage = () => {
    const randomNumberForImagePlaceholder = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    setImages(imgs => [...imgs, randomNumberForImagePlaceholder]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setTxt(e.target.value)}
      />
      <ImgDisplay imgs={images} />
      <button onClick={captureImage}>add image</button>
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render(
  <Example />
);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



And the same demo, but without memo so you can see the log happening when input changes.


const { useState, memo } = React;

const ImgDisplay = ({ imgs }) => {
  console.log("rendering ImgDisplay");
  return (
    <div>
      {
        imgs.map((img, i) => <div key={i}>{img}</div>)
      }
    </div>
  )
};

const Example = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");

  const captureImage = () => {
    const randomNumberForImagePlaceholder = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    setImages(imgs => [...imgs, randomNumberForImagePlaceholder]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setTxt(e.target.value)}
      />
      <ImgDisplay imgs={images} />
      <button onClick={captureImage}>add image</button>
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render(
  <Example />
);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>




I just wanted to add, if the text input isn't changing anything visual as you type, you probably want useRef instead of state. This will prevent it from rerendering your component as well

the problem is with handlechange it should be like this
  const handleChange = useCallback((name, event ) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: event.target.value});
  }, [formData]);


check if getting name params in handleChange , if not then event also have name params inside it


I think you might be confusing TextInput for an input type="text". TextInput is a Native component which has the event handler onChangeText and doesn't return an event as the first argument for that handler, rather it passes the text itself.
